# How to scrape data from Android apps?

Tags: applications

How could you scrape data from an Android app (one without an available API)?

There are some apps that contain personal data I've entered that I'd like to be able to hook into and extract (rather than manual transcribing by hand).

Comment: May I know the name of the app? By knowing the app, perhaps the community can try and experiment with it easily. It's also possible that the app just use SQLite database to store the data, although it's inside internal storage and possibly need root to extract it.

Comment: There is no general solution for this, apps can store data in a million different ways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The app likely uses an undocumented API to communicate with their backend server, so to reverse engineer what this is you need to monitor the app's network traffic. Fortunately this is straightforward for Android:

1. install the Chrome extension [ARC Welder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn) so that you can run Android
   apps on your computer
2. download the app's APK and load it in ARC Welder
3. interact with the app and use a tool such as Wireshark or Fiddler to monitor how the app loads the data you are after from their backend server
4. then replicate this network call to scrape the data directly

See [this blog post](http://webscraping.com/blog/How-to-scrape-Android-Apps/) for more details.

Comment: I have problems with Google Play Services when I use this app.